# bokehで第2のY軸を設定したときに、第1のY軸の範囲が第2のY軸範囲と同じになります。第1Y軸の範囲を明示的に指定することなく、最適な範囲に設定する方法を教えてください。

Tags: python, bokeh

## 環境

- Python3.10.2
- bokeh 2.4.3

## やりたいこと

bokehで折れ線グラフを描画しています。
以下のサイトを参考にして、第2のY軸を設定しました。

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#twin-axes
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199665/

```
from bokeh.models import DataRange1d, LinearAxis
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, save
output_file("graph.html")

x = [0, 1, 2]
y1 = [0, 1, 2]
y2 = [0, 100, 200]

fig = figure(x_axis_label="x", y_axis_label="y1")
y_range_name = "secondary_axis"
fig.extra_y_ranges = {y_range_name: DataRange1d(end=max(y2) * 1.05)}

fig.line(x=x, y=y1, legend_label="y1", color="blue")
fig.line(
    x=x,
    y=y2,
    legend_label="y2",
    color="red",
    y_range_name=y_range_name,
)

fig.add_layout(
    LinearAxis(
        y_range_name=y_range_name,
        axis_label="y2",
    ),
    "right",
)

save(fig)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

## 質問

上記のコードでは、第1Y軸の範囲は、第2Y軸の範囲と同じでした。第1Y軸の範囲が`0~200`と広いため、折れ線の変化が見づらいです。第1Y軸の範囲を`0~10`などもっと狭くしたいです。

第1Y軸の範囲を明示的に指定することなく、適切な範囲にするにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

また`y1`と`y2`を以下の値に変更すると、下図のように第1Y軸の範囲は適切になりました。なぜ、このケースでは第1Y軸の範囲は適切になるのでしょうか？

```
y1 = [30, 230, 650]
y2 = [3, 23, 65]
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

## 補足

### y1,y2のデータ

y1,y2のデータをいろいろ変えて、試しました。

```
y1 = [0, 1, 2]
y2 = [0, 1, 100]
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

y1とy2の値を入れ替えると、第1のY軸の範囲は`y1`の最小値から最大値になりました。

```
y1 = [0, 1, 100]
y2 = [0, 1, 2]
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

つまり、以下であることが分かりました。

- 第1Y軸の最大値が第2Y軸の最大値より大きい場合は、第1Y軸の範囲は最適な範囲になる
- 第1Y軸の最大値が第2Y軸の最大値より小さい場合は、第1Y軸の範囲は第2Y軸の範囲と同じになる

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bokehのフォーラムで教えていただきました。
https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/when-adding-secondary-vertical-axes-the-range-of-primary-axes-is-too-wide/9380/2?u=yuji38kwmt

> By default, a DataRange1d will auto-range using all available glyph renderers, If you want to restrict to only a subset of glyphs, you have to tell it which ones you want by setting the renderers 1 property of the range. The example demonstrates here this:

`y_range.renderers`に`line()`の戻り値を設定することで、解決しました。

```
from bokeh.models import DataRange1d, LinearAxis
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, save

output_file("graph.html")

x = [0, 1, 2]
y1 = [0, 1, 2]
y2 = [0, 1, 100]

fig = figure(x_axis_label="x", y_axis_label="y1")

y_range_name = "secondary_axis"

y1_line = fig.line(x=x, y=y1, legend_label="y1", color="blue")
y2_line = fig.line(
    x=x,
    y=y2,
    legend_label="y2",
    color="red",
    y_range_name=y_range_name,
)

fig.extra_y_ranges = {y_range_name: DataRange1d(renderers=[y2_line])}

fig.y_range.renderers = [y1_line]
fig.add_layout(
    LinearAxis(
        y_range_name=y_range_name,
        axis_label="y2",
    ),
    "right",
)

save(fig)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]